# ASP.NET MVC 5. Как подключать библиотеки JS и CSS файлы для своих HtmlHelpers

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Подскажите как правильно подключать JS и CSS в своих хелперах. Не хочется это делать в PartialView каждый раз.
Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать [Dynamic Bundles](http://debeterevormgever.nl/code/dynamic-bundles) и добавлять скрипты динамический.

Но при это потребуется всегда знать/передавать виртуальный путь к пакету скриптов, чтобы добавить в него новый скрипт.

```
var myBundle = BundleTable.Bundles.GetBundleFor("/myscripts");
```

О пользе [Bundling and Minification](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification).

Comment: Работает. Спасибо. Надеялся, что в ASP.NET есть встроенный механизм для этого, но я не знаю о нем.